# Using generator expression causes Python to hang

Tags: python, generator, list-comprehension

I am experimenting with 2 functions that emulate the `zip` built-in in Python 2.x and 3.x. The first one returns a list (as in Python 2.x) and the second one is a generator function which returns one piece of its result set at a time (as in Python 3.x):

```
def myzip_2x(*seqs):
    its = [iter(seq) for seq in seqs]
    res = []
    while True:
        try:
            res.append(tuple([next(it) for it in its]))   # Or use generator expression?
            # res.append(tuple(next(it) for it in its))
        except StopIteration:
            break
    return res

def myzip_3x(*seqs):
    its = [iter(seq) for seq in seqs]
    while True:
        try:
            yield tuple([next(it) for it in its])         # Or use generator expression?
            # yield tuple(next(it) for it in its)
        except StopIteration:
            return

print(myzip_2x('abc', 'xyz123'))                   
print(list(myzip_3x([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [7, 8, 9])))
```

This works well and gives the expected output of the `zip` built-in:

```
[('a', 'x'), ('b', 'y'), ('c', 'z')]
[(1, 7), (2, 8), (3, 9)]
```

Then I thought about replacing the list comprehension within the `tuple()` calls with its (almost) equivalent generator expression, by deleting the square brackets `[]` (why create a temporary list using the comprehension when the generator should be fine for the iterable expected by `tuple()`, right?)

However, this causes Python to hang. If the execution is not terminated using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> (in IDLE on Windows), it will eventually stop after several minutes with an (expected) `MemoryError` exception.

Debugging the code (using PyScripter for example) revealed that the `StopIteration` exception is never raised when the generator expression is used. The first example call above to `myzip_2x()` keeps on adding empty tuples to `res`, while the second example call to `myzip_3x()` yields the tuples `(1, 7)`, `(2, 8)`, `(3, 9)`, `(4,)`, `(5,)`, `()`, `()`, `()`, `...`.

Am I missing something?

And a final note: the same hanging behaviour appears if `its` becomes a generator (using `its = (iter(seq) for seq in seqs)`) in the first line of each function (when list comprehensions are used in the `tuple()` call).

## Edit:

Thanks @Blckknght for the explanation, you were right. [This message](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2014-November/029961.html) gives more details on what is happening using a similar example to the generator function above. In conclusion, using generator expressions like so only works in Python 3.5+ and it requires the `from __future__ import generator_stop` statement at the top of the file and changing `StopIteration` with `RuntimeError` above (again, when using generator expressions instead of list comprehensions).

## Edit 2:

As for the final note above: if `its` becomes a generator (using `its = (iter(seq) for seq in seqs)`) it will support just one iteration - because generators are one-shot iterators. Therefore it is exhausted the first time the while loop is run and on subsequent loops only empty tuples are obtained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is a bug. It stems from the fact that a `StopIteration` exception bubbling out of a generator is indistinguishable from the generator exiting normally. This means you can't wrap a loop on a generator with a `try` and `except` and look for `StopIteration` to break you out of the loop, as the loop logic will consume the exception.

[PEP 479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/) proposes a fix for the issue, by changing the language to make an uncaught `StopIteration` inside a generator turn into a `RuntimeError` before bubbling up. This will allow your code to work (with a small tweak to the type of exception you catch).

The PEP has been implemented in Python 3.5, but to preserve backwards compatibility, the changed behavior is only available if you request it by putting `from __future__ import generator_stop` at the top of your files. The new behavior will be enabled by default in Python 3.7 (Python 3.6 will default to the old behavior, but it may issue a warning if the situation comes up).

Answer (score 2):

The below is a guess based on the runtime behavior of these codes, not Python language reference or the reference implementation.

The expression `tuple(next(it) for it in its)` is equivalent to `tuple(generator)` where `generator = (next(it) for it in its)`. The `tuple` constructor is *conceptually* equivalent to the below codes:

```
def __init__(self, generator):
    for element in generator:
        self.__internal_array.append(element)
```

Because the `for` statement catches any `StopIteration` as a sign of exhaustion, when the generator raises `StopIteration` because `next(it)` raises it, the `for` statement will simply catch it and think that the generator is exhausted. This is why the loop never ends, and empty tuples are appended: the exception never bubbles up the `tuple` constructor.

The list comprehension, `[next(it) for it in its]`, on the other hand, are *conceptually* equivalent to

```
result = []
for it in its:
    result.append(next(it))
```

So the `StopIteration` is not caught by the `for` statement.

This example shows an interesting nontrivial difference between literal comprehension and the constructor call with a generator expression. The same will happen if one uses `list(next(it) for it in its` vs `[next(it) for it in its]`.

Comment: I could confirm your guess by running codes outside of any loop or function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure about it, but it looks like you have nested generators and outer one catches `StopIteration` raised by inner.

Consider this example:

```
def gen(its):
    for it in its:
        yield next(it)  # raises StopIteration

tuple(gen(its))  # doesn't raises StopIteration
```

It does something equal to what your version does.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
tuple([next(it) for it in its])
```

you are first creating a list, then passing it to `tuple()`. If the list cannot be created because `StopIteration` is raised, then the list is not created and the exception is propagated.

But when you do:

```
tuple(next(it) for it in its)
```

you are constructing a generator and passing it directly to `tuple()`. The tuple constructor will use the generator as an iterator: i.e., will peek items until `StopIteration` is raised.

That is, `StopIteration` is caught by `tuple()`, and is not propagated.

A generator that immediately raises `StopIteration` is converted to an empty tuple.